# PSIM Plot with x-axis replaced by one parameter other than time

Tags: simulation, plot

I am in PSIM and want to get a plot similar to the one below. The plot shows the relationship between two parameters. So, how can I generate this plot? In other words, how can I change the x-axis from time to another parameter?

Credit: the plot is taken from this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346280870_Differential_Equation_Model_of_the_LLC_Resonant_Converter_in_the_Ideal_Case/link/609bc0f1299bf10fbb0bc0d8/download).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the axis tab in the scope. Select "choose x-axis variable"
and choose a desirable parameter.